# Can WCF replace a windows service?

Tags: wcf, windows-services

There is this windows service that runs at mid night every night.For the sake of simplicity, assume that all this service does is delete a log table. If I try to replace it with a WCF (hosted as a windows service) , do I have to call a method on it? Does the WCF have an entry point like the console application Main() method, where it starts something without having to call a method on it?

In a circumstance explained above, does it make sense to replace a windows service by WCF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A windows service is a process running in the back ground, WCF is a communication framework. So your simple answer is no it is not the same and your requirements a windows service is fine.